# Anonymous object with key name with hyphen C#

Tags: c#

I want to create anonymous object which later I want to convert to JSON. But one of key must be named "g-captcha-response" and I am receiving an error

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

```
    new object = new {
       key1 = "val1",
       g-recatpcha-response = "val2"
    }
```

how to make this key name valid? The class also not accept this prop name.

Comment: Are you using Json.Net for JSON manipulation?

Comment: @gunr2171 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert